# Rails - Sagepay - Forcing sandbox mode for transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, opayo

Question as above. I've a form submitting a transaction and I'm trying to use it in sandbox mode to test. Whenever I submit the test details on the site I receive:

```
The IP address of the server sending the transaction does not match the valid IP address ranges listed in the Simulator.
The IP address Simulator sees for your server is ****.
You can add this IP in the Accounts section of Simulator if you wish.
```

I'm assuming when running in sandbox mode this won't be the case, however can't get it to process in sandbox mode..

I've tried using their sandbox details in my secrets.yml file:
http://integrations.sagepay.co.uk/content/sandbox-testing

But when I do I receive

```
Simulator cannot find your vendor name in its database. The simulator saw the Vendor Name 'sandbox' - See more at: http://localhost:5000/portal/expeditions/redland-green-2018/17606/payment-schedule/add-payment#sthash.iuYLoZkL.dpuf
```

Finally in my config files:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
end

ActiveMerchant::Billing::SagePayGateway.simulate = Rails.env.development?
```

When I'm in the form and throw in a binding.pry, ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode returns :test and ActiveMerchant::Billing::SagePayGateway.simulate is true.

Any advice as to how I can get this form to submit in sandbox / testing mode rather than live is greatly appreciated.